# Sticky footer inside MobileAngularUI partial

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I've got a partial view that I want to have a sticky footer on.  Unfortunately the scrollable div overflows with my footer no matter what I try.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="scrollable">
            <div class="scrollable-content">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a ng-repeat="msg in chatmessages" href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="bubble bubble-{{msg.dir}}">{{msg.text}}</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <form class="row row-chat">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="messageText" placeholder="Type your message" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Custom CSS:

```
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
}

#footer {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fix the footer with the specifec height like using styles

```
    #footer
{

top:1200px;
left:300px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as the viewport is going to be different sizes across multiple platforms.  I am looking for a solution that works by utilizing AngularJS.